# How get content before specific character in a text using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, mapping

Below is a part of xml and i want to map to map it to a value but i dont want the whole text only a part of it, below is the sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
<school type="HIGH" id="123445565SSFFGHG_GT_204444446"></school>
</Company>
```

I want a xpath condition that gets only  first portion id seperated by underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`substring_before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-before), e.g. like in the following example:

```
substring-before (Company/school/@id, '_')
```